# Best way to change field value before it reaches the webapi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```cs
[ApiController]
Route("v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
        private readonly IClient _client;
        public AccountController(IClient client,)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction([FromBody] SomeRequestModel request)
        {
            if (_client.SomeId == null) return BadRequest("Something could not be resolved");
            request.SomeId = _client.SomeId.Value;

            // Do further processing
        }
}
```

SomeRequestModel.cs

```
public class SomeRequestModel 
{
    public long SomeId;
    // other fields
}
```

There are about 100 different actions that take in about 100 different request models. But those models don't inherit from a single class that has `SomeId` field. Changing the requests is not feasible since they are from another project.

I need to check if `SomeId` is resolved and return BadRequest or set the field. But I dont wnat to write these 2 lines on every request. What would be the best way of handling this. Or just writing the lines okay.

I thought of using `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` and parsing the body as json and updating the value there but that seems extremely inefficient.

Comment: Which .net version are you using?

Comment: 7.0 ...................................

Comment: Can't you have a middleware which does this logic for you?

Comment: @ertucode please check the updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy. You need to apply a model binder to SomeRequestModel. Here is an example

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction([FromBody] SomeRequestModel request)
    {
        return Ok(request.SomeId);
    }
}

[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(SomeRequestModelBinder))]
public class SomeRequestModel
{
    public long SomeId { get; set; }
    // other fields
}

public class SomeRequestModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeRequestModel>(json);
            model.SomeId = model.SomeId + 100;
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 1:
Peter paid attention that you need to update 100 models. It is also can be achieved by implementing IModelBinderProvider. Here is an updated version.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction([FromBody] SomeRequestModel request)
    {
        return Ok(request.SomeId);
    }
}

public interface IHaveSomeId
{
    long SomeId { get; set; }
}

public class SomeRequestModel : IHaveSomeId
{
    public long SomeId { get; set; }
    // other fields
}

public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, bindingContext.ModelType);
            if (model is IHaveSomeId someIdModel)
                someIdModel.SomeId = someIdModel.SomeId + 100;
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
    }
}

public class MyModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder? GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        return new MyModelBinder();
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:
If you do not have an interface that all models can implement, the value can be modified with reflection or expression trees. The example below uses reflection.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction([FromBody] SomeRequestModel request)
    {
        return Ok(request.SomeId);
    }
}

public class SomeRequestModel
{
    public long SomeId { get; set; }
    // other fields
}

public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var doc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDocument>(json);
            if (!doc.RootElement.TryGetProperty("SomeId", out JsonElement someIdElement))
                throw new BadHttpRequestException("No SomeId in the request.");

            var model = doc.Deserialize(bindingContext.ModelType);
            TryToUpdateSomeId(model);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
    }

    private void TryToUpdateSomeId(object? model)
    {
        if (model == null) return;
        var propInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty("SomeId");
        if (propInfo == null)
            return;

        var getMethod = propInfo.GetGetMethod();
        var setMethod = propInfo.GetSetMethod();
        if (getMethod == null || setMethod == null)
            return;

        var currentValue = (long)getMethod.Invoke(model, null);
        setMethod?.Invoke(model, new object[] { currentValue + 100 });
    }
}

public class MyModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder? GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        return new MyModelBinder();
    }
}
```

Do not forget to register the provider.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyModelBinderProvider());
});
```

Comment: This solution would require 100 Binder classes. (*There are about 100 different actions that take in about 100 different request models.* from the question)

Comment: The solution can be easily modified. The only thing that should be added is to implement IModelBinderProvider. I've updated the code.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I feel like the performance hit is not worth it.

Comment: Performance can be drastically improved with cached expression trees. I mentioned it in my answer. However, it's out of the scope.